# I'm trying to write a blog about future tech and science - where can I find ideas?

Tags: research, blog, science

I watch Isaac Arthur and John Michael Godier; I’m looking for a site to help me write an online blog, that talks about a future science tech or idea every week (or every month; depending on my schedule). The site should

- be ongoing and consistently at once a week or month with new ideas, and
- postulate SPECIFIC and oftentimes creative ideas, and
- recommend amateur stuff.

Comment: You find ideas about the future of technology and science by reading about current events in technology and science rather than following the blog of some one else who constantly reads about current science and technology.  You want the sources, not somebody else's summary some few current events.

Comment: I write a personal blog about my experiments in electronics.  I find new ideas by being active on the electrical engineering stack exchange.  Most of my experiments come directly from questions asked on the site.  I actively take part on the EE site, so I am constantly exposed to these ideas.  Similarly, you should be active in some field that exposes you to the new science and technology idea you want to blog about.  You must be active, rather than a passive consumer of other blogs who writes a derivative blog.

Comment: I've edited your tags to remove 'writer's block' (your question isn't really about that) and added [tag:research] instead.

Comment: @JRE, that comment sounds like it should be an answer (and get upvoted).  Comments are for *improving the question*, not suggesting solutions!

Comment: @TobySpeight:  Judging by the downvotes, this question not strictly on topic.  I'm active on other Stacks, and try to point people towards a solution even when it looks like the question itself is going to be closed.  I'd rather comment on a question that'll get closed than answer it.

Comment: I’d recommend graduate school in one of the STEM fields. Then, with an education, maybe even a Ph.D, you can read (and understand journals) on science, tech, and apply that information to problems of our world.  Start with posers wanting to blog about stuff they are ignorant of. Address that disease of the ego and it may apply to so many other topics that hold humanity down.

Answer (score 1):

I can only add that "I want to write, but I don't know what to write about" should be a tell. It's like someone saying "I want to be a pop star, but I don't have any music I want to play or sing."

If you don't have any ideas, then maybe you shouldn't even think about writing a blog, because it will probably just be a rehash of other people's ideas. There are already too many "journalists" who are just reading the Web and "reacting" to it.

Another tell is that you say "postulate SPECIFIC and oftentimes creative ideas." If you have these ideas, then there's your blog. If you don't, then put in the time to master some specific part of science and technology. If you're lucky, that mastery will lead you to some really unique insights that other people aren't already writing about.

Answer (score 0):

I would also look into searches for terms like "Emerging Technology", "Near Future", and "Futurism/Futurist".   That said, if this is for fiction, you should develop tech trends in your own world and then have a consistent explanation.  For example, in one near future sci-fi, I had a planned EPCOT style city (the theme park was intended by Walt to be a functional city, but got scaled back after his death) and the dominant form of entertainment had moved into Augmented Reality.   Gamers were now seen wearing AR glasses and were more physically active than we think (and this was in development before Pokemon Go became a big name success for AR Gaming... at the time, Google Glass was being hyped... and that did not pan out.), but AR was also seen for more mundane uses...  most of the dashboard information on the cars were now displayed on the windshield as AR displays and cops behind the one way glass in interrogations could pull up a suspects rap sheet through AR projections on their window.

Fictional Near-Future Scifi is less about the technology as it is exploring the society once the technology becomes commercially affordable so the common man can interact with it.   The trick here is to follow how tech trends enter the public. It might be critical to look at historical game changing techs as well as fad techs.  Getting a good look into the 90s when this new thing called "the Internet" entered peoples lives.   The 80s are a good tech boom period as well as personal computers were starting to become a thing.  One thing I had in background notes for my AR is that of course there are a lot of applications for AR Porn because both the VCR and many internet innovations were done because it could make Porn more available (the VCR was the winner over the better quality Beta Max because the later refused to allow Porn on the system.   Encryption of Credit Card information that made online shopping possible was the result of people not wanting their credit card info to get out to anyone when porn sites were hacked.).

For a good series, check out Joss Whedon's tv series "Dollhouse" which was made with late 2000s asthetic in mind and took a simple premise of programmable people and rapidly upped the ethics of the technology on a society that wasn't ready for it, from the user's lack of understanding of what they were doing to the unseen benefits, to first adoption (as is want, the titular organization is the first commercial use of this innovation... and it's more than once likened to a high end brothle.  Though that aspect is rarely seen as the episodes mostly feature clients who see other potential uses.).

Comment: The OP is specifically intending to write a **blog.**  A blog about fictional advances in science and technology in a fictional world sounds like it kind of misses the mark.

Comment: @JRE, the question is tagged [tag:science-fiction], making this answer appropriate, but I'm not convinced that it's what the questioner meant.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest that you sign on to one of the sibling stack exchanges. Namely, [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). It meets your criteria for the type of site you are seeking.

> The site should be
>
> •Ongoing and consistently at once a week or month with new ideas
>
> •Postulates SPECIFIC and oftentimes creative ideas
>
> •Amateur stuff is highly recommended

Worldbuilding SE

- Consistently and on an ongoing presents new ideas -- and much more
  often than once a week or a month. Plus it has a background of ideas
  in the form of questions.
- The ideas are often specific and creative
- The ideas are often amateur

You can certainly find a veritable cornucopia of science-oriented ideas that highly speculative, creative, sometimes interestingly realistic, and occasionally improbable on Worldbuilding SE.

This is recommended as a starting point for ideas for your blog. Good luck with doing that!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for new ideas, find other blogs, look at websites for print magazines in the popular science genre and see what their headline stories are.

You don't COPY them, but the work of figuring out what is new in science is already done for you. Bigger outfits have full time professionals reading arxiv and Google Scholar. Pick a currently hot topic, do your research and write your blog.

if you want to do it yourself; go to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), put in a search term like "Biology and Medicine", or "Artificial Intelligence", then use the filters on the left to narrow the date range down, and sort by date. Look for titles that interest you, and hopefully you are qualified to say something about. These are all academic articles, by the way, the authors will typically include reasons what they are doing is important, in the abstract. But the writing is considered by most to be dry. Making it non-dry is your job.

The value of this approach is you can pick a general topic in which you have some expertise, and pick something only recently academically published (often that means it is original, but it might be a survey or review of the current state of the art), so it may not have been written about before, or had much attention.

Look specifically for papers where the PDF or PostScript is available, or that provide a free site for that.

Answer (score 0):

At least for one segment of futurism, I recommend just general Youtube channels about current events in space, like Marcus House, Everyday Astronaut, and Scott Manley. They put out a lot of videos on where this specific aspect of futurism is going.